# For what $ \alpha \in \mathbb R$ is $ |x|^\alpha $ differentiable in $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, exponentiation, absolute-value

I came across the following question:

> For what $ \alpha \in \mathbb R$ is $ |x|^\alpha $ differentiable in $x=0$?

What I have tried:

Since for $ \alpha = 1 $ is clearly non-differentiable in $x=0$, let's consider $ \alpha < 1 $ and $ \alpha > 1 $.

If $ \alpha < 1 $:

\begin{align} 
\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} &= \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{|0+h|^\alpha-|0|^\alpha}{h}
 \\ &=  \lim_{h\to 0^+} h^{\alpha-1}
 \\ &=  +\infty
\end{align}

So there is no need to check the case $\lim_{h\to 0^-}$.

After doing the same for $ \alpha > 1 $ we get $\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = 0$. And from the left side:

\begin{align} 
\lim_{h\to 0^-} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} &= \lim_{h\to 0^-} \frac{|0+h|^\alpha-|0|^\alpha}{h}
 \\ &=  -\lim_{h\to 0^-} \frac{(-h)^\alpha-0}{-h} \mbox{ (piecewise definition of abs)}
 \\ &=  -\lim_{h\to 0^-} (-h)^{\alpha-1}
 \\ &=  0
\end{align}

So I concluded that $ |x|^\alpha $ is differentiable in $x=0$ for $ \alpha > 1 $ and non-differentiable for $ \alpha ≤ 1 $.

Yet after thinking a bit more two questions came into my mind:

a) Isn't it a problem that if $ \alpha $ is irrational $x^\alpha$ is defined only for $x>0$?

b) What about the $0^0$ case?

Comment: $0^0$ is defined to be $1$. (There is one mapping $\emptyset\to\emptyset$ and it is the $\emptyset$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusions are correct.

a) You're looking at $|x|^\alpha$; since $|x|>0$, rational powers of negative numbers are not an issue.

b) The case $\alpha=0$ can be dealt with separately easily.

Comment: Here is what I meant: how can we talk about whether $|x|^\pi$ is differentiable in $x=0$ if it's not even defined in $x=0$?

Comment: @Ruslan $0^\pi=0$ is certainly defined.

Comment: @anon, I thought that for irrational $\alpha$ it's defined only for $x>0$ since $x^\alpha := \exp(\alpha \log x)$ and $\log 0$ isn't defined. What am I missing here?

Comment: You're missing that $0^x$ is defined to be $0$ for all $x>0$.

Comment: @anon, oh, I see. Thank you for looking into it.

Comment: Btw, if you define $\log 0$ to be $-\infty$ and define $\exp(-\infty)$ to be $0$ then you get $0$ again.

Comment: @anon, I've noticed another issue with my solution: if $\alpha < 0$ the function isn't even defined for $x=0$. So the full solution would be: differentiable for $\alpha = 0$ or $\alpha > 1$ and non-differentiable for $0< \alpha ≤ 1$. Does it make sense this time?