# Find a function $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $|f^{(j)}(s)| \leq k(1+|s|)^{p-j}$ for $j=1,2$

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

I would like to know if there is a twice differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that:

- $f(0)=0$;
- $|f'(s)|\leq c_1(1+|s|)^{p-1}$;
- $|f''(s)|\leq c_2(1+|s|)^{p-2}$;

for all $p \in \left[1,\frac{n}{n-2}\right)$, where $n \geq 3$ is a fixed natural number.

**My attempt:** Let $f(s)=|s|^{p-1}s$. Then,

- $f(0)=0$;
- $f'(s)=(p-1)|s|^{p-1}$.

However, following this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346923/for-what-alpha-in-mathbb-r-is-x-alpha-differentiable-in-x-0), the function $f'(s)=p|s|^{p-1}$ will only be differentiable when $p-1>1$, that is, $p>2$.

Comment: What about the function $f(s)=se^{-s^2}$?

Comment: Is there an easy way to check the conditions in the derivatives of this function?

Comment: Take $f'(s)=-(2s^2-1)e^{-s^2}$ and choose $p=1$ so that the bound is $c_1$. Choosing $c_1=1$ is sufficient. Now take $f''(s)=2(2s^3-3s)e^{-s^2}$. I guess $c_2=4$ so it boils down to check if $|(2s^3-3s)e^{-s^2}|\leq2(1+s)^{-1},\forall s\geq0$ and $|(2s^3-3s)e^{-s^2}|\leq2(1-s)^{-1},\forall s < 0$

Comment: @Snoop I don't know if I can choose $p=1$. I would need an estimate for every $p$ in the range $[1,n/(n-2)]$ with $n \geq 3$ fixed.

Comment: Ok. Put $\forall p \in [1,n/(n-2))$ in the question then.

Comment: In the title: The $j$-th derivative of $f$ is usually denoted $f^{(j)}$, with $f^j$ more often meaning $\underbrace{f \circ \cdots \circ f}_j$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(s)=c_1s$ satisfies all the conditions.